# Installing vue-i18n causing error with vite

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vite

Trying to install vue-i18n with no luck, please see my error bellow

```
npm install vue-i18n
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: MPS@undefined
npm ERR! Found: vue@2.7.14
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   dev vue@"^2.6.12" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^3.0.0" from vue-i18n@9.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/vue-i18n
npm ERR!   vue-i18n@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/yohanesai/.npm/_logs/2023-05-24T17_16_32_468Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/yohanesai/.npm/_logs/2023-05-24T17_16_32_468Z-debug-0.log
```

Have try with `--legacy-peer-deps`, I can install it but when trying to `npm run dev` is going to more crazy, (more error). So I think the error is important and I can't avoid the error. This is the error if I insist to install the vue i18n

```
Error: Build failed with 3 errors:
../../node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.esm-bundler.js:8:9: ERROR: No matching export in "../../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js" for import "createVNode"
../../node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.esm-bundler.js:8:22: ERROR: No matching export in "../../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js" for import "Text"
../../node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.esm-bundler.js:8:70: ERROR: No matching export in "../../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js" for import "Fragment"
```

What I missed here? I use node `v19.8.1` and npm `9.5.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lib version dependency error, in this case you are using Vue 2, and vue-i18n@9.2.2 needs Vue3, so you need upgrade Vue2 to Vue3(maybe i will brake your actual code) or downgrade vue-i18n to [8.x](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n)

Comment: thank you for the answer, you are right. after `npm install vue-i18n@8`, the error was gone. Please accept my greatest appreciation to mark your answer as an accepted answer :D good day!